# How to call all Patients with same ID but measurement value only appeared once

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am working on a large Dataset with Patient data on UTI. I now want to merge all the rows of same patients when they have once number smaller then 10 000 KBE/ml into one row saying Pathogen = negativ.

I provided some toy data for illustration. The data in itself is very messy. But I hope to get an solution here. I tried to make work of the if_else function but i didn't know how to tell R that if_else should not only run on the specific row where KBE/ml is smaller then 10 000 but on all when they have the same Pat_ID.

| Pat_ID | Pathogen |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | E.coli |
| 1 | 100 KBE/ml |
| 2 | 100 000 KBE/ml |
| 2 | Staph. aureus |
| 3 | Proteus mirabilis |
| 3 | 10 000 KBE/ml |
| 4 | E.coli |
| 4 | 1000 KBE/ml |

What I want to get:

| Pat_ID | Pathogen |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | negativ |
| 2 | 100 000 KBE/ml |
| 2 | Staph. aureus |
| 3 | Proteus mirabilis |
| 3 | 10 000 KBE/ml |
| 4 | negativ |

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion. First, I stripped all the alphabets and symbols from `Pathogen` and created a new columns `var`. Then, change the corresponding values in `Pathogen` to negative. Finally, remove the rows with organisms grouped by `Pat_ID` if there is a negative.

```
dat <- read.table(
  text = "Pat_ID    Pathogen
1   E.coli
1   100 KBE/ml
2   100 000 KBE/ml
2   Staph. aureus
3   Proteus mirabilis
3   10 000 KBE/ml
4   E.coli
4   1000 KBE/ml",
header = TRUE, sep = "\t"
)

library(tidyverse)

dat1 <- dat %>% 
  mutate(
    var = str_remove_all(Pathogen, "[A-Za-z]|\\.| |\\/"),
    Pathogen = if_else(var != "" & as.numeric(var) < 10000,
                       "Negative", Pathogen)
    ) %>% 
  group_by(Pat_ID) %>% 
  filter(max(Pathogen == "Negative") == 0 |
           max(Pathogen == "Negative") == 1 & Pathogen == "Negative") %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-var)

dat1

# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   Pat_ID Pathogen         
#    <dbl> <chr>            
# 1      1 Negative         
# 2      2 100 000 KBE/ml   
# 3      2 Staph. aureus    
# 4      3 Proteus mirabilis
# 5      3 10 000 KBE/ml    
# 6      4 Negative
```